# Make and receive calls on your Mac, iPad, or iPod touch

Tags: ios, macos, ipad

I read following article on apple site, I want to know how the media is transferred to the network provider if the call is accepted from MAC/iPad.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209456

I am developing webrtc based calling app, is it possible to support same feature in my app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming they're using low-layer C or C variant code that takes the incoming audio and sends it out as either TCP or UDC packets over the local network.

Because you are using a browser, you do not have access to the low-level microphone API. WebRTC does support sending audio peer-to-peer, but both endpoints have to have your website open.

Comment: Ours is an application like Viber or Skype, is it possible in this case. but how to signal mac/iPad